# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module NextJs and Gulp

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gulp, i18next, next.js13

I'm trying to implement `i18n-perser` with Next Js. According to the `i18n-perser` documentation I need to create a `gulpfile.js` on the root directory. My `gulpfile.js` is something like this.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import { gulp as i18nextParser } from 'i18next-parser';

export async function i18next() {
  return gulp
    .src('./**')
    .pipe(
      new i18nextParser({
        locales: ['en', 'nl'],
        output: './i18n/locales/$LOCALE/$NAMESPACE.json',
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
}
```

It's gives me `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I tried some solution like the dynamic import. But it's not working for me in this case. It's giving me the same `SyntaxError`.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const gulp = dynamic(() => import('gulp'), { ssr: false });
const { gulp: i18nextParser } = dynamic(() => import('i18next-parser"'), { ssr: false });
```

I triend the `dynamic import` but it's also not working in my case. It's working perfectly in `React` but not working with `NextJs`. Basiclly if I run `npm run gulp` it will create parer file for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your project is set to use the CommonJS [module system](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) by default.

In that case, you could rename your `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.mjs` to keep using the `import` syntax.

Comment: Its working after renaming the gulpfile.js to gulpfile.mjs. But it's giving me this error now. FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: @SabbirZzaman You should ask a new question for that.